# Are all SSD the same apart from capacity?

Tags: laptop, ssd, laptop-repair

I have a notebook ASUS UX330U and I suspect that the SSD has stopped working. I want to buy a new one to replace it, but before doing so I want to know which SSD I should buy, or what things I should take into account to choose the new SSD. The datasheet of the notebooks reads "256GB SATA3 M.2 SSD".

Is physical size a problem or are all the same size? Is there any problem with connectors or do they all use SATA ports? Do they all consume the same amount of power or should I take this into account too? Any other characteristics that may occur to you are welcome as well.

Comment: "SATA3 M.2 SSD" it more like a card that is slotted into a connector on the motherboard, not the conventional sata connector. More info here....https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/M2-SSD

Comment: You are overthinking this: All you need to do is get an SSD drive that is an M.2 card. Past that, it doesn’t matter. The M.2 card format is the physical connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just learnt this yesterday so anybody with experience is free to correct my answer.

No SSDs are not the same. The have different storage capacity, speeds, form factors and connectors.

In your particular case your physical connector is M.2 (there exist others SATA, PCIe) which is a small connector directly on the motherboard. Now aside from the connector you need to know which form factors fit into your machine there are a few different ones denoted in mm (ex. m.2 2280 means m.2 connector 22mmx80mm form).

Now aside from being able to connect and fit your SSD into your system you want to be able to use it to it's full speed potential. This will depend on the controller/interface your motherboard supports. You meantioned SATA (currently the fastest one is NVMe) which is an older protocol. You can read the motherboards or manufacturer's manual to know what the motherboard supports.

Basically your SSD performs as fast as the weakest link in the chain even if you get one that can outperform your current computer.

To sum it all up:

- pick a storage capacity (ex. 256Gb)
- get the right form factor that fits your machine (ex. M.2 2280)
- optional: if you really want your SSDs speed to match your machine learn what interface/controller your motherboard supports (most M.2 SSDs are faster than SATA3 therefore your SSD will be slowed down by your motherboard).

Comment: Your answer is sound. I would add that - different SSDs are made using different memory technology (eg transistor size and stacking) which can greatly affect the reliability and durability, as well as different controllers which does likewise. Other differences include the amount of over provisioning if cells (more over provisioning means longer SSD life) and quality of support componentry - eg extra caps/supercaps which can finish a write if power is suddenly lost.

Comment: “No SSDs are not the same. The have different storage capacity, speeds, form factors and connectors.” This is a “[truthy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truthy)” statement. Yes, all those differences exist. But the main factor in the case of SSD drives is the connector: In a broad sense you either have a classic SATA connection or you have an M.2 connection and that is that. Past that, the specifics of storage capacity and speed is no different than the differences between hard disk drives. If the issue is simply drive replacement, the data connection being  SATA or M.2 is the main concern.